# Opening Link in System Browser in PhoneGap 3.3 on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I've been searching for an answer but it seems most of what I've found is for older versions of PhoneGap.

Here is my link code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://acq.com/account/', '_system', 'location=yes');">My Account</a>
```

This code does absolutely nothing. I click the link and nothing happens.

And yes, I have phonegap.js added on the HTML page.

Anyone know what else I would need to do to get this to work. This is the ONLY link in the PhoneGap app that I want to do this. :/

Answer (score 2):

As strange as it sounds, you need to have the InAppBrowser plugin installed in your project to be able to launch links in an external browser.

See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Comment: Just replyed as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(path,{ openExternal:true })
```