# Open a link in the default browser of a system with cordova 3 and jquery mobile

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova-3

Hi I'm working around with jquery mobile and cordova 3 on a android device.

Everything works great except that I can't open links in the default browser or for example the maps application.

I can open it with a inappbrowser plugin but I dont want to do that. I just want to open the links to websites with the default browser.

I tried many things like here:

[Opening Link in System Browser in PhoneGap 3.3 on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273735/opening-link-in-system-browser-in-phonegap-3-3-on-android)

[Open Links in Default Browser using Phonegap/Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484648/open-links-in-default-browser-using-phonegap-cordova)

But I saw that the answers are showing the solution with the inappbrowser which I dont want.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android OS use following code.

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("http://google.com", {openExternal : true});
```

or through inline JavaScript:

```
<a onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('https://google.com/', { openExternal:true });">Link</a>
```

It will NOT work with iOS, also, I don't know, if currently exist a solution for iOS, that don't require **inappbrowser**.

Comment: Hello Gajotres, your inline tag is not working. It does not do anything if I click the link

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, I just created a working project just so I can test this.

Comment: I run cordova 3.4.0 and jquery mobile 1.4.0 and installed the inappbrowser plugin. Maybe I have to remove the plugin?

Comment: Ok its now woking with links. Thanks for that. But how about if I want to forward to the default maps application?

Comment: Yes you can: <a href="geo:38.897096,-77.036545">Geolocation Test</a> but this is beside the point of this question. Because this answer solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).

Comment: @Kingalione Did you get it to open the links in an external browser, or did you end up using the InAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: Eirik Hoem yes it is working on android but not on ios.